# ionic serve - lots of errors after installing Ionic deploy

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I've recently setup Deploy with Ionic Pro for my Ionic application. However, now whenever I run `ionic serve` I get this errors:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available`

`Error loading deploy information. No Plugin Available`

I know that Cordova is not available in the browser, but how can I tell the app to stop searching for the plugin while testing with `ionic serve`?

Answer (score 0):

First import Platform,

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(platform: Platform, ...)
```

After import the plugin you want to use in the browser into this if block

```
if(platform.is('cordova')) {...}
```

Comment: Where do I have to check this? I already have it in app.component.ts, but the updates run automatically, there's no code for them in my files.

Comment: Which plugins are you using?

Comment: cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.2 
cordova-plugin-battery-status 2.0.1 
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.2
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 2.0.2
cordova-plugin-ionic 4.1.6
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 2.3.3
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1
phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.3

Comment: Can you use? 
` npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular@latest
npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova@latest `

Answer (score 0):

please check `app.component.ts` file check below code you can remove that condition

```
if(platform.is('cordova')){}
```

Comment: I don't uderstand, I have this code in my app.component.ts, but why should I remove it? It doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the plugin to work for the browser you should add `platform browser` and run it:

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

and run it:

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

instead of `ionic serve`.